# how to upload images to digital ocean space using php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am using Spaces-API-master library for uploading images to digital ocean space using core php. But I am getting error:

> SpacesAPIException:
>   {"error":{"message":null,"code":null,"type":null,"http_code":null}}

I am using library from this: [github.com/SociallyDev/Spaces-API](https://github.com/SociallyDev/Spaces-API).

here is my code

```
require_once("vendor/autoload.php");  
$key = "xxxx"; 
$secret = "xxxxxx"; 
$space_name = "xxxx"; 
$region = "sgp1"; 
$space = new SpacesConnect($key, $secret, $space_name, $region); 
$path_to_file = "image.png"; 
$space->UploadFile($path_to_file, "public");
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: Please show the **essential** code to reproduce your problem. Your question, as it is written now, needs more details to 

be answered. Please read [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)
and [**How to Ask a Good Question**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: if you could show us a code snippet and possibly a link to the library you're using, we'll be able to help you further.

Comment: What is throwing the exception? the `spacesConnect()` call or the `$space->UploadFile()` call? You need to be aware that most likely the `$path_to_file` variable needs to be the full server path relative to you front controller (there's a CI global for that `FCPATH`), so unless the image is exactly in the same directory as your main codeigniter `index.php` you'll need to be more specific as to where the file actually is

Comment: $space->UploadFile() call is throwing exception

Comment: and  you're certain that the `$path_to_file` value points to the full server path of the file you wish to upload?

Comment: yes,i have checked path by displaying in front end.whenever i am calling UploadFile() i am getting internal server error.i checked in log life and it's showing SpacesAPIException error.i am not getting what's the issue becoz of which everything in error  msg are comming as null.

Answer (score 0):

I came to this question when i am trying to upload images recursively and need to create additional directory in the space. This is simple php method to get it done.

```
# if you need to display all errors if there is any
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// include the classes  PATH_TO_LIB defined in your config    
require(PATH_TO_LIB . 'aws/autoloader.php');
require(PATH_TO_LIB . 'spaces.php');
        
$key = "YOUR KEY";
$secret = "YOUR_SECRETE";
$space_name = "YOUR_SPACE_NAME";
$region = "YOUR_REGION";
// Initialise the space
$space = new SpacesConnect($key, $secret, $space_name, $region);

// I am expecting the relative path of the file to be upload
$source = "SOME_FOLDER/image.JPG";
$filename_on_space = "image.JPG";

$space->UploadFile($source, "public","path/to/directory/" . $filename_on_space, "image/jpeg");
// this will upload the file with public permission with specified mime type
```

Upload file function have following arguments, be noted for mime type.
UploadFile(Source file, ACL (Public|private), path_on_space_with_filename, mime_type)

Additional tip : If you want to create a directory on space simply use

```
$path_to_file = "FOLDER_name/"; //dont miss the last slash
$space->UploadFile($path_to_file, "public","sub/folders/" . $path_to_file, 'text/directory'); // be noted for the mime type for the folder
```