# how to check if folder exists before upload images to digital ocean space

Tags: php, digital-ocean

I took this answer from [how to upload images to digital ocean space using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60568086/how-to-upload-images-to-digital-ocean-space-using-php)

The question is how to check if the folder exist on digital ocean space before adding a file please?

```
$source = "SOME_FOLDER/image.JPG";
$filename_on_space = "image.JPG";

$space->UploadFile($source, "public","path/to/directory/" . $filename_on_space, "image/jpeg");
```

create a directory on space:

```
$path_to_file = "FOLDER_name/"; //dont miss the last slash
$space->UploadFile($path_to_file, "public","sub/folders/" . 
$path_to_file, 'text/directory'); // be noted for the mime type for the folder
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check existance of file or directory using php function ***file_exists***

```
if(file_exists($path_to_file)){
 // do your logic
}
```

please also check documentation https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php

Comment: I meant if the directory exist on the digital ocean space